# Uno platform: ListView has uneven item spacing

Tags: listview, uno-platform

I have a `ListView` with variable height rows. For Android, the gap between items is not correct, in two ways. For UWP, it displays correctly.

First, in the screenshot below, notice that the first two items have a narrow gap and the rest have a larger gap. Second, my gap should be one XAML unit tall.

[image]

I am creating the gap with a 1 unit bottom margin, as you can see in the XAML below. Notice, in the picture, the first gap, between two multi lined items, is thin. Then the next gap, between a multi lined and single lined item is bigger. And then, between single lined items, it is even bigger.

XAML:

```
<Page x:Class="UnoTest.ListPage" ...>

  <Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      ...
      <Style x:Key="ListViewItemStretchStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
      </Style>

      <DataTemplate x:Key="NoteItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel Padding="10" Margin="0,0,0,1" Background="PowderBlue">
          <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Note}" />
        </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
      ...
      <local:DetailListSelector x:Key="DetailListSelector"
        NoteItemTemplate="{StaticResource NoteItemTemplate}"
        ...
      />

    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Page.Resources>

  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions ... />

    <ListView Grid.Row="2"
      x:Name = "DetailList"
      Margin="0"
      Padding="0"
      ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemStretchStyle}"
      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
      Background="LightGoldenrodYellow"
      ItemsSource = "{x:Bind DetailListItems}"
      ItemTemplateSelector = "{StaticResource DetailListSelector}">
    </ListView>
    
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

There isn't anything particularly interesting in the C# code-behind. But, if you think otherwise, please let me know and I'll add some snips.

Comment: Hey, you are successfully finding many hidden bugs for us  ! Can you report this on Uno GitHub please?

Comment: Already is, per request of Jérôme: https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/issues/5071